# Can no longer access contacts in Evolution

Tags: 12.04, evolution

A couple of weeks ago, when I tried switching to the Contacts tab of Evolution, the entire application froze. Well, that sometimes happens with Evolution – so I simply called `killev`, also took care all its sub-processes were terminated, and restarted it. Same thing still: As soon as I want to switch to contacts, Evolution freezes – and `killev` reports `No response from Evolution -- killing the process`.

Now I thought this might be due to several library and kernel updates without reboot, there might be some mismatch – and the "Windows repair method" would fix it. Having finished the other open tasks, today I finally rebooted the machine. To my surprise, this did *not* fix the issue – behaviour is still the same: as soon as I try to access contacts, Evolution freezes.

**System:** Ubuntu 12.04 (and no, updating to 14.04 or 16.04 is not an option for this machine)
**Evolution:** 3.4.2-1ubuntu3.1~stracciatellappa+precise1 (same version for -common, dataserver and plugins); evolution-webcal: 2.32.0-2ubuntu2.1~stracciatellappa+precise1; evolution-indicator: 0.2.20-0ubuntu7

In my `~/.xsession-errors` I see a couple of warnings related to Evolution:

```
(evolution:4096): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
(evolution:4096): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `EABContactDisplay'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing the "Submit" button on my question, I just wondered about another application: About the time this issue started, I've installed `syncevolution` to get my ownCloud contacts/calendars synced (the build-in WebDAV sync in Evolution is a bit itchy). Never found the time to configure it, though – so just to be on the save side, I ran an `apt-get remove --purge` on its 4 packages (`syncevolution*`). Should have thought about that earlier: issue solved!

Obviously there are conflicts between those packages (syncevolution 1.2.2-1 and above mentioned Evolution packages), so removing syncevolution resolves the conflict.